# NullPointerException, when resuming application

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, onresume

I recently stumbled upon what appears like a `onResume` issue when I load my application, back all the way out and relaunch it. This results in the application  crashing. I saw a few examples of other people overriding the `onResume` call and say `super.resume` but that approach is not working for me. Would it be possible to store the data in a `savedInstance` and retrieve it `onresume`? Can someone review my code and try and help me figure out where the problem is? I tried debugging but I just end up with 10 different .java windows open.

EDIT: I did some more digging and was able to pinpoint where the error is occuring so I set a break point and stepped through the code until it crashed. It looks like a string variable comes back "null" after I back all the way out of my application and re-open it. I'm not sure why the value is not being restored, so I'll have to research writing the data to a file and retrieving it later or the onSaveInstanceState()  Does anyone know or have an idea why my initial values fail to re-assign in the intents at the bottom? Maybe because the app thinks it is starting a second activity?

**LoginActivity.java**

```
/**
 * A login screen that offers login via email/password.
 */
public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    /**
     * A dummy authentication store containing known user names and passwords.
     * TODO: remove after connecting to a real authentication system.
     */
    private static final String[] DUMMY_CREDENTIALS = new String[]{
            "foo@example.com:hello", "bar@example.com:world"
    };
    /**
     * Keep track of the login task to ensure we can cancel it if requested.
     */
    private UserLoginTask mAuthTask = null;

    // UI references.
    private AutoCompleteTextView mEmailView;
    private EditText mPasswordView;
    private View mProgressView;
    private View mLoginFormView;
    public String webResponse = null;
    public String finResponse = null;
    String email = mEmailView.getText().toString();
    String password = mPasswordView.getText().toString();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        // Set up the login form.
        mEmailView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
        populateAutoComplete();

        mPasswordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        mPasswordView.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                if (id == R.id.login || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                    attemptLogin();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        Button mEmailSignInButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.email_sign_in_button);
        mEmailSignInButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                attemptLogin();
            }
        });

        mLoginFormView = findViewById(R.id.login_form);
        mProgressView = findViewById(R.id.login_progress);

        attemptLogin();
    }

    private void populateAutoComplete() {
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }


    /**
     * Attempts to sign in or register the account specified by the login form.
     * If there are form errors (invalid email, missing fields, etc.), the
     * errors are presented and no actual login attempt is made.
     */
    public void attemptLogin() {

        // Reset errors.
        mEmailView.setError(null);
        mPasswordView.setError(null);

        // Store values at the time of the login attempt.


        boolean cancel = false;
        View focusView = null;


        // Check for a valid password, if the user entered one.
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(password) && !isPasswordValid(password)) {
            mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_password));
            focusView = mPasswordView;
            cancel = true;
        }

        // Check for a valid email address.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_field_required));
            focusView = mEmailView;
            cancel = true;
        } else if (!isEmailValid(email)) {
            mEmailView.setError(getString(R.string.error_invalid_email));
            focusView = mEmailView;
            cancel = true;
        }

        if (cancel) {
            // There was an error; don't attempt login and focus the first
            // form field with an error.
            focusView.requestFocus();
        } else {
            // Show a progress spinner, and kick off a background task to
            // perform the user login attempt.

            showProgress(true);
            mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask(email, password);
            mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
        }
    }

    private boolean isEmailValid(String email) {
        //TODO: Replace this with your own logic
        return email.contains("@");
    }

    private boolean isPasswordValid(String password) {
        //TODO: Replace this with your own logic
        return password.length() > 4;
    }

    /**
     * Shows the progress UI and hides the login form.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
    public void showProgress(final boolean show) {
        // On Honeycomb MR2 we have the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs, which allow
        // for very easy animations. If available, use these APIs to fade-in
        // the progress spinner.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
            int shortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);

            mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            mLoginFormView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                    show ? 0 : 1).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });

            mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            mProgressView.animate().setDuration(shortAnimTime).alpha(
                    show ? 1 : 0).setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                }
            });
        } else {
            // The ViewPropertyAnimator APIs are not available, so simply show
            // and hide the relevant UI components.
            mProgressView.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            mLoginFormView.setVisibility(show ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int i, Bundle bundle) {
        return new CursorLoader(this,
                // Retrieve data rows for the device user's 'profile' contact.
                Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI,
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.CONTENT_DIRECTORY), ProfileQuery.PROJECTION,

                // Select only email addresses.
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE +
                        " = ?", new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email
                .CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE},

                // Show primary email addresses first. Note that there won't be
                // a primary email address if the user hasn't specified one.
                ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.IS_PRIMARY + " DESC");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader, Cursor cursor) {
        List<String> emails = new ArrayList<String>();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            emails.add(cursor.getString(ProfileQuery.ADDRESS));
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        addEmailsToAutoComplete(emails);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> cursorLoader) {

    }

    private interface ProfileQuery {
        String[] PROJECTION = {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.ADDRESS,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.IS_PRIMARY,
        };

        int ADDRESS = 0;
        int IS_PRIMARY = 1;
    }


    private void addEmailsToAutoComplete(List<String> emailAddressCollection) {
        //Create adapter to tell the AutoCompleteTextView what to show in its dropdown list.
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(LoginActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, emailAddressCollection);

        mEmailView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    /**
     * Represents an asynchronous login/registration task used to authenticate
     * the user.
     */
    public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

        private final String mEmail;
        private final String mPassword;
        Context myContext;

        UserLoginTask(String email, String password) {
            mEmail = email;
            mPassword = password;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO: attempt authentication against a network service.

            try {
                // Simulate network access
                String localWebResponse = null;
                webCreate web = new webCreate();
                try {
                    localWebResponse = web.sendPost("https://www.msn.com/account/login.action", "login_url=&login_email=popcorn@sally.com&login_password=butterPlease&offeredNotListedPromotionFlag=");
                    finResponse = web.sendPost("https://www.msn.com/account/calculateBenchmarkData.action", "");

                    if (localWebResponse.indexOf(("Account Summary"))>= 0) //Probably logged in
                    {
                        //Load activity_li_summary view then transform/extract data
                        webResponse = localWebResponse.toString();
                    }

                    else //Probably not logged in.
                    {

                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //call custom web class.

                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return false;
            }

            for (String credential : DUMMY_CREDENTIALS) {
                String[] pieces = credential.split(":");
                if (pieces[0].equals(mEmail)) {
                    // Account exists, return true if the password matches.
                    return pieces[1].equals(mPassword);
                }
            }

            // TODO: register the new account here.
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
            mAuthTask = null;
            showProgress(false);

            if (success) {
          //makes it here
               // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), webResponse, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Summary.class);
                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                extras.putString("SD", webResponse);
                extras.putString("FD", finResponse);
                intent.putExtras(extras);
                startActivity(intent);

//                finish(); //appears to close app.

            } else {
                mPasswordView.setError(getString(R.string.error_incorrect_password));
                mPasswordView.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    }
}

Stack Trace

05-21 11:09:52.413    1185-1185/com.myApp.myAppName E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myApp.myAppName, PID: 1185
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myApp.myAppName/com.myApp.myAppName.Summary}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2540)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5748)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.myApp.myAppName.MSI.getNameValueCash(MSI.java:60)
            at com.myApp.myAppName.Summary.onCreate(Summary.java:63)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5600)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2504)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:174)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5748)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code line by line to see on which line does it crash? Also have you checked logcat window to see the crash reason?

Comment: the problem comes from `Summary.class` so the Summary Activity. Can you please send the *Summary.java*